# How to use cvxopt with DSDP?

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I'm trying to use DSDP (semidefinite programming package) with cvxopt. I have both of them installed (matlab version for DSDP). I have Python 2.5.2.

When trying to use

```
dsp(..., solver='dsdp')
```

I get an errors mentioning solvers.dsdp is not installed.

How to I make them work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest asking this question on the [cvxopt](http://groups.google.com/group/cvxopt) group.